# angularfire load the data from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I don't know how to access the data which I receive from Firebase, here is the object:

```
0:Object
$$hashKey : "object:4"
$id : "-KPoOlGpoArhMjgPLms_"
$priority : null
$value : "{"name":"jone","phone":null,"company":null,"email":null,"workPhone":null,"address":null}"
__proto__ : Object 
1 : Object
$$hashKey : "object:5"
$id : "-KPoOvSLgVFxa0ca7qaL"
$priority : null
$value : "{"name":"jone","email":"bdaa@ds.cokm","phone":null,"company":null,"workPhone":null,"address":null}"
__proto__ : Object
```

how do I retrieve the info that I need, like: $id and $value is the fields I need

here is my controller:

```
var db = fireBaseApp.instance.database().ref('contacts');
 $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(db);
 $scope.contacts.$loaded().then(function (data) {
   $scope.cont = data;
   console.log($scope.cont);
 });
```

so I need to get the data

Answer (score 2):

Method One:

```
var users = null;
function allContacts() {
users = $firebaseArray(db.child('contacts'));
}
return users;
}
```

Or use this also

```
function allContacts() {
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/contacts')
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded().then(function() {
  angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value, key);
  });
});
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works, but It is not updated when I add a new record to firebase, I have used the 2nd method